# Express req.ip switches between reporting my local machine address as ::ffff:127.0.0.1 and ::1 on a seemingly random basis

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So basically the title says it all.

For the past few hours I have been working on a middleware function that relies on cookies for authentication, something very simple like this:

```
const authRoute = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.ip);
    // some other logic here
    return next();
};

app.use('/admin/', authRoute, adminRouter);
```

The thing is, I haven't modified any of my other code such as for example `app.set()` or even the `app.use()` itself, I have been working on this middleware function exclusively. I am also storing this `req.ip` in my database for auth purposes.

Well, to my surprise this very same `req.ip` object all of a sudden started to result in:

```
::1
```

just after an application/server restart for seemingly no reason. Right before that it was reporting back to me:

```
::ffff:127.0.0.1
```

I can verify that because I am console logging this and storing the value in a database as well.

[image]

For the record, `req.connection.remoteAddress` is the same, and I don't have any special settings such as `trust proxy` or anything like that enabled, I haven't reached that stage of development yet.

So I am really scratching my head right now of what might be causing this, so any help or input is appreciated. I can provide further details as well such as my `bin/www` config if necessary.

I am on a Win7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `req.connection.remoteAddress` , i have used it many times with success .
This answer is crystal clear https://superuser.com/questions/668004/why-is-my-localhost-not-127-0-0-1-but-1-and-what-notation-is-that

Comment: I've read what you posted but I still don't understand why `req.ip` randomly just reports `::1` one time and `::ffff:127.0.0.1` another time. And I also noticed that it doesn't even take a server restart sometimes. I am honestly super confused by this.

Comment: It is a network issue , windows sometimes use ::ffff:127.0.0.1 and sometimes use a shorten version ::1 it is the same ip . Check if you want here for details https://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7/436944#436944

Comment: thanks a ton for the resources you linked, will do some more detailed reading once again tomorrow. But from what I am reading so far, and correct me if I'm wrong, one can conclude that this random behavior can be attributed to some Windows weirdness going on in the way it chooses the preferred connection and what takes precedence (IPv4 vs IPv6).

Answer (score 1):

Check the string for leading `::ffff:` and remove it then the remaining is IPv4, otherwise (without leading `::ffff:`) it is an IPv6.

The reason you are getting different IPs for `localhost` is sometimes the request is coming as IPv4 (`::ffff:127.0.0.1`) and sometimes as IPv6 (`::1`).

Anyway you need to take care of both versions in production.

Comment: Can you tell me why some requests might be coming as IPv4 and others as IPv6 (on a random basis), because literally all I am doing is refreshing the same browser tab using the same address like `localhost:3000/admin`. I'd really appreciate it if you can tell me what the logic behind that behavior is or at least point me to some article.

Comment: If you enter `localhost:3000/admin` in browser, then it is up to how it is translated to IP (dns). Usually `localhost` is hard-coded in [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).

Comment: All I have in the hosts file is `::1 localhost` and `127.0.0.1 localhost` in the same order, but that doesn't explain why it would randomly switch between ::1 and and 127.0.0.1. One would think that ::1 would always take precedence since it's the first entry.

Comment: Then somehow your OS translates `localhost` to either of them randomly. I have no idea about that (some networking app may intervene, etc).

Comment: Yeah, the OS could possibly be the issue. I need to do some more testing and possibly on a fresh installation to determine what is going on. Also thanks for your input, I appreciate it. Once I (hopefully) manage to figure all of this out I will edit my answer and possibly mark accepted reply as well, depending on the results. Cheers.